# Laravel 5.1 name routes error

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I need your help for something I not understand.

I am learning Laravel with a few tutorials (in spanish, my language) from this page: https://styde.net/proyectos/

First I done the *Curso básico de Laravel 5* without problem ([link to tutorial](https://styde.net/laravel-5/)).
But now, I am doing *Curso de Laravel 5.1* ([link to tutorial](https://styde.net/curso-introductorio-laravel-5-1/)) I found a problem.

On third point on first part, shows how Laravel add routes into *routes.php*.

I have this url (copied from Laravel documentation) and works fine:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

But the teacher shows how make a change.
He removes the 'auth/', being the new code this:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

After, he shows how to use 'names' and he makes other change:

```
Route::get('login', [
'uses'  => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin',
'as'    => 'login'
]);
```

He goes to form, and change the action by

```
{{ route('login') }}
```

Finally he clicked on button (the form is for login, only email and password).

The response shows the errors: email and password are empty. It's ok.

But I have a important error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:
```

[image: error screenshot]

Can someone help, please?
Than you!!

Comment: Are you sure to have a controller name `AuthController` and inside it a PUBLIC function name `getLogin` ? Can you link the controller ?

Comment: I have `AuthController` into Auth folder into Controllers. And I don't have a public function called `getLogin`.
But the teacher not did it and works fine for him.

Also, if I not remove 'auth/' it works for me, but the URL is not `mydomine.com/login`, is `mydomine.com/auth/login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two routes:

```
Route::get('login', array(
   'uses'  => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin',
   'as'    => 'getLogin'
));

Route::post('login', array(
   'uses'  => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin',
   'as'    => 'postLogin'
));
```

To go to login page use `URL::route('getLogin')` and in form action use `URL::route('postLogin');` and make sure you have this 2 methods inside Auth\AuthController! `getLogin` performs return of the view, and `postLogin` post data for login process!

Answer (score 0):

You have `Route::get`, but i think it should be `Route::post`.

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` says that You make wrong type request (eg. trying make POST to GET route)

Comment: Your solution makes not shows this error, but not shows app errors like 'the email field ir required' or something.

Also, I access to data base only for get values, not for modify. For this reason he route should be 'get', or not?